# how to add space between column BOOTSTRAP 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I add space between these two columns.

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6 shadow">
            ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6  shadow ">
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to add custom margins to bootstrap columns without breaking the behavior of its grid layout on various responsiveness intervals.

You could use `offset-*` utility classes, but that will actually offset that column by a number of columns, not by a random amount of pixels.

A rough example of using it would be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 shadow">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 shadow offset-md-2">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

---

By far, ***the easiest way*** to do it is to place a wrapper inside the column and use margins on that. In your case, I guess you want the space between them for the shadow to render nicely, so simply create an extra `<div>` and move `.shadow` on that one:

```html
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="shadow">
          ...
       </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="shadow">
          ...
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now playing around with `.shadow`'s margin is easy and it doesn't break the grid layout.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your desire. You can add space between HTML elements using margin and padding [(Box model)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). In bootstrap, it is possible by `m-0`-`m-5` for margin and `p-0`-`p-5`. You can specify position and size for different viewports too. See more [detailed informations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/)

Remember: Padding is offset of inner content. Margin is outer offset and may break your layout (col-6 + m-5 is bigger than 6 col grid)